# Create new Repositories while still using Dependency Injection with wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-sql, dependency-injection

I have a wcf service that takes in an IRepository

```
IRepository irepo;

public SomeService(IRepository repo)
{
    this.irepo = repo;
}
```

The repositories contain methods like Save, Delete, etc and take in a CustomDataContext through a constructor:

```
public class ExampleRepository: IRepository, IDisposible {

   public ExampleRepository(CustomDataContext datacontext)
   {
       this.dc = datacontext;
   }

   ...
}
```

Later on in the service i have a few methods that will need to use a repository (and later dispose of it in the method). Now since i want to use Dependency Injection to switch out repositories for testing and not testing, how do i declare the concrete repository. I could create a new Instance of the repository like so:

```
using (IRepository repos = (IRepository)Activator.CreateInstance(irepo.GetType(), new object[] {new CustomDataContext()} ))
{
     ...
}
```

but im assuming this is a slow way of doing it (and incorrect)

Is there a way to do make a new Repository based on the injected type, or am i just making things more complicated then necessary?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this article: http://bit.ly/bF7jL3. It gives a how to enable unit testing your code while using LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole idea of dependency injection is that there's some container which resolves your dependencies for you. Is there a reason your not using a framework for injecting your dependencies, say structuremap or unity for example?

If you do have a container you should request a new instance of your type from the container which instantiates it for you and resolves all the dependencies if any for you of that specific type.

Comment: ah. I didn't think about requesting a new object from the container each time i wanted a new Repository. I guess i was stuck in the constructor injection mindset. Thanks

Comment: Well even when doing constructor injection it is important to request new instances from your container as your container can inject the proper dependencies into the newly constructed type.

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting `Func<CustomDataContext, IRepository>` if your container allows such behavior. Otherwise, inject a `IRepositoryFactory` which would have a `CreateInstance` method.